# Can't save plot as png file ( Error using hgexport)

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to save a plot as png (i.e. other formats suffer from this problem) via save as but I got this error

```
Error using hgexport
Error using print
Too many input arguments
```

Any suggestions? Matlab R2016a

Comment: Thanks to detail the error message, but it would equally useful to also show the code that generated the error ...

Comment: @Hoki, I wish the error is too long, but this is what I got. Any simple code yields this error. Probably this has nothing to do with the code but some corrupted or wrong directory for the print function.

Comment: `Too many input arguments` signals that there is definitely something wrong with **the code**. Are you able to reproduce this error with a complete sample set of data and instructions ? If yes then please detail it in your question.

Comment: @Hoki I’m using the plot window. No code for using print. File>Save as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `which print`, it seems there is a user-defined function whose name is `print` in this folder

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\MATLAB\print.m
```

Matlab is probably trying to call this function instead of the one which is defined in here

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\print.m
```

This is really awkward. Matlab should alter users when they name functions with already built-in functions. After renaming the user-defined function, Matlab successfully saved the figure as png.